# Explore a multiple values dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I would like to explore a dictionary with multiple values
For example, function_test(groups) would give me as a result:

```
{153: {’sport’, ’travaux manuels’, ’cinephiles’, ’cuisine’},
538: {’sport’}, 147: {’cinephiles’, ’cuisine’},
802: {’sport’, ’travaux manuels’, ’cinephiles’, ’cuisine’},
125: {’travaux manuels’, ’cinephiles’}}
```

The problem is, I don't know how to explore values of a dictionnary and how to give new values to a new dictionnary.

```
# membres_hobbies : dict[int:set[str]]
membres_hobbies = {153:{'patisserie','sushi','natation','Almodovar'}, 
125:{'Harry Potter','dentelle','cinema'}, 
538:{'boxe','cyclisme','judo'}, 
147:{'HBO','Harry Potter','sushi'}, 
802:{'bricolage','cyclisme','Almodovar','sushi'}}



# groupes : dict[str:set[int]]
groupes = {'cinephiles':{802,125,147,153}, 
'travaux manuels':{125,802,153}, 
'cuisine':{153,147,802}, 
'sport':{153,538,802}}





def te(group):
    """ Problème Dictionnaire Question 1
        dict[str:set[int]] -> dict[int:set[str]]
    """

    # D : dict[int:set[str]]
    D = {}

    # (k, v, w) : tuple[str, int, int]
    for k,v in group:
            D[v] = D[v] + k




    return D
```

Comment: can you tell me what do you want as result ? the dict with name membres_hobbies or groupes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the dictionary is saved as follows

```
x = {153: {'sport', 'travaux manuels', 'cinephiles', 'cuisine'},
     538: {'sport'}, 147: {'cinephiles', 'cuisine'},
     802: {'sport', 'travaux manuels', 'cinephiles', 'cuisine'},
     125: {'travaux manuels', 'cinephiles'}}
```

## Accessing elements using a key

To access elements in your dictionary you can use your **keys**. A list of your keys can be extracted by

```
list(x.keys())
```

> [153, 538, 147, 802, 125]

Now if you want the values associated with a key you can access them by

```
x[153]
```

> {'cinephiles', 'cuisine', 'sport', 'travaux manuels'}

## Adding new keys to the dictionary

To add a new key with values to a dictionary you do

```
x.update({100: {'wow', 'un', 'autre', 'francais'}})
x[100]
```

> {'autre', 'francais', 'un', 'wow'}

This adds a new set at the hash address 100.

## Adding new values to a set saved in your dictionary

You dictionary contains sets. You can add values to these sets as well by

```
x[100].update({'bonjour'})
x[100]
```

> {'autre', 'bonjour', 'francais', 'un', 'wow'}

This access the dictionary element hashed by the value 100. Then updates that set with the new value.

---

Your specific case can be solved by

```
dic = {}
for key in groupes:
    for val in groupes[key]:
        if val in dic: dic[val].update({key})
        else: dic.update({val: {key}})
```

---

Using list comprehension

```
groupes = {'cinephiles':{802,125,147,153}, 
'travaux manuels':{125,802,153}, 
'cuisine':{153,147,802}, 
'sport':{153,538,802}}
dic = {}

[dic[val].update({key}) if val in dic else dic.update({val: {key}}) 
 for key in groupes 
 for val in groupes[key]]

dic
```

> {125: {'cinephiles', 'travaux manuels'},  
>   147: {'cinephiles',
>   'cuisine'}, 
>  153: {'cinephiles', 'cuisine', 'sport', 'travaux
>   manuels'}, 
>  538: {'sport'},  
>  802: {'cinephiles', 'cuisine', 'sport',
>   'travaux manuels'}}

Comment: Thank you so much !!! And, there is not a way with something like: Dic = Dic + v instead of .update?

Comment: No I do not think there is a + operator to add elements to a dictionary. I always use `.update()`

Answer (score 0):

What you want is called a reversed index, here is how to create one in this specific case.

```
groupes = {
    'cinephiles':{802,125,147,153}, 
    'travaux manuels':{125,802,153}, 
    'cuisine':{153,147,802}, 
    'sport':{153,538,802}
}

def function_test(groups):

    result = {}

    # You can loop through key-value pairs of a dictionary using dict.items()
    for hobby, id_set in groups.items():

        # You can loop through a set normally
        for id in id_set:
            try:
                # Add the key, by example 'sports', to the id entry
                result[id].add(hobby)

            except KeyError:
                # If the id is new, the above will fail and we need to create a set

                # You can assign to a dictionnary like this
                result[id] = {hobby}

    return result

function_test(groupes)
```

It also turns out Python can achieve this with a fairly readable oneliner.

```
result = {
    id: set(k for k in groupes.keys() if id in groupes[k])
    for id in set.union(*groupes.values())
}
```

Both solutions output:

```
{153: {'travaux manuels', 'cinephiles', 'cuisine', 'sport'},
 802: {'travaux manuels', 'cinephiles', 'cuisine', 'sport'},
 147: {'cinephiles', 'cuisine'},
 125: {'travaux manuels', 'cinephiles'}, 
 538: {'sport'}}
```